# Lazarus/Delphi/Pascal: выполнить процедуру, зная ее имя, содержащееся в строке

Tags: windows, winapi, delphi, lazarus, linux

Я пишу некое подобие командного интерпретатора и мне необходимо запустить процедуру/функцию по строке, содержащей ее имя.

Вот [этот](http://www.procomp-blog.ru/programming/delphi-vyzov-procedury-po-stroke-s-eyo-nazvaniem/) способ я видел, но он не работает в Linux - просто не компилируется(не может найти `WinApi` функции `GetModulehandle` , `getprocAddress` и тип `HWND`).

Что делать?

Comment: >>"свойство objects будет хранить адреса нужных процедур." - Вот в этом вся и проблема - я не знаю, как в linux получить адрес процедуры - может, надо модуль подключить какой-нибуь?

Comment: не нужно ничего подключать. адрес получается просто - через `@` или `addr()`.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. А можно для этих целей использовать записи или лучше не надо?

Comment: можно и записи, но вот только скорее всего то нужно будет хранить массив пар "имя" - "адрес". А StringList как раз это умеет. Более того, если элементы отсортировать, то поиск по списку будет с логарифмической сложностью. Правда, если у Вас 10-15 функций, то толку с этого мало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужен универсальный способ, то нужно сделать себе какой нибудь TStringList со списком всех нужных функций и процедур и свойство objects будет хранить адреса нужных процедур. Либо написать своего наследника от TList, тогда можно будет легко сделать даже проверку аргументов.